# Events A & B - Probability

Tags: probability

The probability of A occurring is $A={5\over9}$, the probability of B occurring is $B=0.65$ and the probability of B occurring but not A is 1/6

1. Find the probability when both events A and B occur
2. Find the probability when event A occurs when it is known that event B does not occur

Comment: What you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:
$$P(B) = P(B - A) + P(B\cap A).$$

Comment: For which one a. or b. ?

Comment: The probability of $B$ occurring butnot $A$ is $P(B - A)$.

Comment: And is P(B∩A) the probability of both of them happening ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: But i already know that the probability of B occurring butnot A is 1/6